# Pin Mapping of nRF2401L01+ using Adafruit's nRF24L01+ library

Tags: communication, nrf24l01+

I have an Arduino Uno and one of these nRF24L01+ from china (see image)
[image]

To use the module i wanted to use the library provided by Adafruit (http://playground.arduino.cc/InterfacingWithHardware/Nrf2401). My problem is, that they're using different names for some pins, because the library is designed for a different module with the following pin outs.

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/2aT18.jpg]

I don't know which PIN from the China module corresponds to the DAT and DR1 Pin on the Adafruit module.

So my questions are:

1. Is it OK to use the library in conjunction with the china module?
2. What are the DAT and DR1 PIN on the module from China ?

What I know so far:
- took a look into the library and into the documentation at playground.arduino.cc/InterfacingWithHardware/Nrf2401 and found out that the DR1 pin is for the available() function to check if data is available to be read.

Comment: Compare these two schematics and you have the answer; http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Nordic/nRF2401A-Chip-v11.pdf and http://mcuoneclipse.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/nrf24l01-schematic.png?w=584&h=359

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DR1 is MISO
DAT is MOSI
```

Though I'd advice using the [RF24 library](https://github.com/tmrh20/RF24/), as it's a lot more recent than the one from 2009 you linked to.

Comment: Plus it supports additional layers like RF24Mesh and RF24Network that allow you to create simple, multiple node networks.

Comment: Thanks for the pin mapping! I will take a look at the library you both mentioned.